# Capturing packets getting only payload

Tags: scapy, tcpdump

I need to get only the payload of network packets (without Ethernet header). I used TCPDump, I get something like :

```
 0x0000:  4500 013f 7913 4000 4006 72ee ac10 01e3  E..?y.@.@.r.....
0x0010:  c732 d894 b826 0050 9455 3f65 51f9 a5f4  ./...&.P.U?eQ...
0x0020:  8018 0990 4ee9 0000 0101 080a 0079 6387  ....N........yc.
[...]
```

I also tried with Scapy :

`>>>hexdump(p)
0000   00 19 4B 10 38 79 00 26  5E 17 00 6E 08 00 45 00   ..K.8y.&^..n..E.
0010   00 40 90 E7 40 00 40 11  26 66 C0 A8 01 0E C0 A8   .@..@.@.&f......
0020   01 01 97 F1 00 35 00 2C  06 5A 6E 18 01 00 00 01   .....5.,.Zn.....`

Do you know how to get only the middle column? (preferably all on one line)
(I tried Tshark, but it doesn't correspond to my expectations)

Thanks

Comment: It would help to know why you want it... You can use Wireshark's "Follow TCP Stream" option to see the whole TCP stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [tcpick](http://tcpick.sourceforge.net/) project on sourceforge that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wireshark to analyzes the packets.And also you get more  detailed description